# ModelSim waves rendering is slow

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, modelsim

I switched from version 6.6d (SE) to 10.1c (SE).
In the old version, the waves appeared immediately after completing the simulation. Now it takes a long time to wave rendered. 
Where could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the resolution of the simulation, is it in pico, nano or something else? If you are clocking your design at a nano scale and the simulation is set up to display everything in ps it will take much longer time to render the waves.